# Is there a way to include ViewBag.CurrentFilter in my input?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Making a searchbox, so im courious if i could implement the existing one into new style one.

I have a searchbox thats working and its commented in the code. Id like to include viewbag in my new searchbox but i can find a way how

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" onfocus = "this.value=''" value="@(ViewBag.CurrentFilter)" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary"  type="submit">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            @*<div class="col-auto">*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("Search", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { onfocus = "this.value=''", @class = "form-control", @id = "form-font", @placeholder = "Search", @style = "border-radius:0px", @autocomplete = "off" })*@
                @*<button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>*@

            @*</div>*@
        }
```

Button is working couse i tried it on the other searchbox, but when i type text in searchbox nothing happens when i click the search button

Comment: ViewBag.CurrentFilter is null???

Answer (score 0):

For `Post`, you should use from `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` and use `type="submit"` for input tag html.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="col-auto">
     @Html.TextBox("Search", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { onfocus 
= "this.value=''", @class = "form-control", @id = "form-font", @placeholder = 
 "Search", @style = "border-radius:0px", @autocomplete = "off" })
 <input type="submit" /><span class="fa fa-search"></span>

        </div>
}
```

Comment: Yea i realize that. Id like to implement that code in <input> in my first <div>